# Pandas concat mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have two pandas dataframes with the same number of rows:

```
(16363, 17872)
(16363, 5)
```

I want to concatenate them side by side, so I run:

```py
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Which results in a completely unexpected shape:

```
(23006, 17877)
```

So, I have right number of columns (17872 + 5 = 17877), but a seemingly random number of rows.

What can cause this?

Comment: It alligns on the indices, so if the index of the dataframes is not the same, it will not set them next to each other. What would solve it is: `pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)`

Comment: I think we need some more information here. As @Erfan already mentioned it could be due to not matching indices but as long as we don't know how the 2 dfs look like its hard to give you a good answer